# My UWP custom EMPTY interface is not a valid Windows Runtime type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, uwp, background-task

In my C# UWP solution I created a Library(Universal Windows) which has and empty interface inside a namespace that matches with the project/assembly name.

```cs
namespace PersonCore
{
  public interface IPersonService{}
}
```

The implementing class is empty as well and they belong to the same namespace.

Then I have a Windows Runtime Component project where I have a class that accepts in the constructor a parameter of the type of my interface

```cs
namespace PersonApiBackgroundTask
{
 public class PersonWorker
 {
   public IPersonService PersonService { get; set; }
   public PersonWorker(IPersonService personService)
   {
     this.PersonService = personService;
   }
 }
}
```

I'm getting the following error related to the worker's contructor

> Method 'PersonApiBackgroundTask.PersonWorker..ctor(PersonCore.IPersonService)' has parameter 'personService' of type 'PersonCore.IPersonService'.  'PersonCore.IPersonService' is not a valid Windows Runtime parameter type.

and the error related to the worker's PersonService property

> Method 'PersonApiBackgroundTask.PersonWorker.PersonService.get()' returns 'PersonCore.IPersonService', which is not a valid Windows Runtime type.  Methods exposed to Windows Runtime must return only Windows Runtime types.

What I'm doing wrong?

I read the documentation but I'm not able to find out the solution. I know that there are some restrictions when implementing a windows runtime component but I don’t have any clue why my scenario is not even compiling.

I tried without success:

- Added to the interface a method with Int type as parameter. The implementing class has no body in the method.
- Set the worker namespace the same as the interface.

Comment: have you checked this: [Declaring types in Windows Runtime components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/creating-windows-runtime-components-in-csharp-and-visual-basic#declaring-types-in-windows-runtime-components)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the Target component of my Library to Universal Windows Component. That change guided me to multiple issues I had in the library, like no sealed public classes.